# macOS - How to install Java 17

Tags: java, macos, javafx

Could someone please let me know the steps to install Java on a Mac.

I did `brew install java`

I get this

```
Warning: openjdk 17.0.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 17.0.1, run:
  brew reinstall openjdk
```

If I do java -version, I get this.

```
openjdk version "13.0.8" 2021-07-20
```

If I have navigate to `/Library/Java`, I have 2 empty directories.

Where is java 17 installed??

Comment: I like [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). Then `sdk install java 17.0.1.fx-librca` to install the current release from Liberica (with included JavaFX). Or `sdk ls java` to see the various other current releases.

Comment: +100000 for sdk man as Elliott suggested above. The main benefits of it is that you can have multiple versions installed, switch them whenever you need and (very important in case something goes wrong) they are installed in your home directory.

Comment: java 17 is likely found where brew installed it under `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Java doesn't mind if you install multiple versions. This is often required; java is not backwards compatible (it tries to change little, but e.g. the java8 to java9 transition broke a ton of stuff, much of it needless and much of it not reasonably expectable or fixable by libraries and apps, so a bunch of java apps and libraries only run on java8 - just an example).

So, yes, you have installed JDK17. Also, yes, if you just run `java` without specifying which one you want, you so happen to get java13 here.

To see all installed javas, you can run:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

to 'override', you can use something like (depends on which shell you're using on your mac):

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`
```

(the backticks mean: Run this then take the output of it and treat that as the 'value' of the expression. here, assign it to the JAVA_HOME env var. `-v 17` requests a path to java 17. The `-V` option lists all and is meant for your eyeballs, not for scripts. The `-v` option is mostly for scripting, and that's how we're using it here).

`JAVA_HOME` decides which java is used by some things, but the `java` you get when you just type `java` is `/usr/bin/java`, and that executable is actually just a wrapper that picks a java to run from amongst all installed versions. It uses JAVA_HOME to decide which java to actually run. There are wrappers for all the common commands (`javac`, too). You can always run e.g. `which javac` to see what that actually runs; you probably see `/usr/bin/javac`. Everything in `/usr/bin` is one of these wrapper thingies that looks at JAVA_HOME and then runs the binary it finds *there*.

Comment: This works. But when i close the terminal this doesn't get saved, it resets back to the old java version. how to permanently save this?

Comment: Put a `JAVA_HOME=` command in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile` - some file that is run by the system itself.

Answer (score 260):

### In 2024, even if you can use just `brew`..

```
brew install openjdk@17
```

Java will be installed here:

```
/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java
```

for Apple Silicon path is `/opt/homebrew/...` rather than `/usr/local/...`

For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

resp. for Silicon

```
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk\@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Now, running `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` should show the path to JAVA 17, something like:

```
17.0.9 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17.0.9" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.9/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(This is what you are missing btw, if `javac` or `javac --version` does not give you a command-not-found but an `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.`)

In case you see the wrong version, check if the path to `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly. If not, you could set it by:

```
export JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

## ...give a try to [`sdkman`](https://sdkman.io/), it's far better than `brew`

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

then open a **new shell** and try `list` to see what you could install ;-)

```
sdk list java
```

At time of writing you could use:

```
sdk install java 17.0.4.1-tem
```

Java will be installed here:

```
/Users/freedev/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.4.1-tem
```

Comment: sdkman is the way to go! Versions installed with brew are not recognized by Eclipse.

Comment: @Gert-Jan so do you think the answer should be updated leaving only `sdkman`?

Comment: Not sure about that, brew may be fine for some use cases but doesn't work when you try to configure the installed JDK in Eclipse.

Comment: @Gert-Jan the full JDK is in the `libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home` subdir.

Comment: sdkman was the best solution for me among all answers. Give it a chance

Comment: Can someone explain to me why there are different VENDORS for a programming language? This is mind-boggling to me, if I want a version of Python I get that version. If I want a version of Go, I get that version. For example, if I am on macOS, is one vendor better than another here?

Comment: With Homebrew it was installed to:

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17

On my machine.

Comment: @Tbi Pay attention during the installation there is a message "If you need to have openjdk@17 first in your PATH, run:
  `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`". Because `/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17 -> ../Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.5`.

Comment: Better how and why?

Comment: @Tbi is right, for my m1, path was `/opt/homebrew/...` rather than `/usr/local/...`

Comment: @BlackChase thanks for letting me know. I’m going to update the answer.

Comment: @RukshanJS IMHO sdkman is more focused on managing software development kits while homebrew is more general-purpose. I understand your comment but I don’t like to add too many infos in my answers (and this is one of the longest answers I have ever written). This is good for clarity, to get the people straight to the point.

Comment: @freedev thanks for that clarification. It clears my doubt. Again, thanks for the answer but wanted to have some basic idea why it's better. Cool!

Comment: @fullStackChris this is an odd comment. There are actually multiple implementations of python (cython, jython, IronPython), there are multiple implementations of go (gcc-go and gc) and there are multiple implementations of, say, the C language (too many to count). If the language has been well specified, multiple implementations are to be expected.

Answer (score 29):

To specify version 17

```
brew install openjdk@17
```

Later I add create a link:

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk \
     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk
```

And use [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/) to control which java version to use

Answer (score 9):

To used the version installed by homebrew rather than the one installed by the OS you can get detailed information from homebrew by typing

```
brew info java
```

Currently it states

> For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
> sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
>
> openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
> because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
> parallel can cause all kinds of trouble. 
> If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc 
> For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I found this later.

Answer (score 7):

For Homebrew, the package that installs the new AdoptOpenJDK is named as temurin. So you need to use below command:

```
brew install --cask temurin17
```

If you get any error like temurin cask not available then update brew using below commands:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

To switch quickly between different versions of java add the entries in bashrc as per your jdk versions like:

```
alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version"
alias j17="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`; java -version"
```

Answer (score 4):

## Steps to install

You asked:

> let me know the steps to install Java on a Mac.

1. Download an installer free-of-cost from vendors such as [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/), [Azul Systems](https://adoptium.net/), Bellsoft, [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/), Oracle, Microsoft, SAP, and others.
2. Run installer app.
3. Quit the installer app when done.
4. Verify installation by typing on a command-line in Terminal.app:
   `java --version`
5. Delete installer app that you downloaded.
6. Configure your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to use that new Java implementation you installed.

## Java location

You asked:

> Where is java 17 installed??

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

In the Finder, choose *Go* > *Go to Folder*, and paste `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.

Note that this is *not* the `Library` folder within your home folder. We are *not* referring to `/Users/your_user_name/Library/…`. We are referring to the root `Library` folder that applies across [all the user accounts](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac) on this Mac.

You said:

> I did brew install java

No need for the [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) package manager. If you already enjoy using the `brew` tool, proceed. But if new to Homebrew, skip it if your only goal is to install Java. Just use an installer for Java as you would for many Mac apps.

## *JavaFX*

You added a tag for `javafx`.

Be aware that for JavaFX, you have two options:

- Include the necessary [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries within your development project and within your final app, *or* …
- Use a JDK that includes the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries.

At least two vendors provide JDK installers that include the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries:

- Azul Systems (*ZuluFX*)
- Bellsoft (*LibericaFX*)

Comment: Is it not 'java -version'? I think you have 2 dashes where there should be 1.

Comment: @amalgamate Both work, `java -version` and `java --version`. [Both are documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java) as being standard options.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using SDKMAN on macOS to switch between JAVA 11 and 17 based on the project I'm working on, it's pretty easy

```
 curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash 
 source "/users/#USER_HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
 sdk list java
 sdk install java #JAVA_IDENTIFIER
 sdk use java #JAVA_IDENTIFIER
```

Then each time switch using

```
 sdk list java
 sdk use java #JAVA_IDENTIFIER
```

You could also allow your IDE such as Intellij to use the system console bash, so you could switch using SKD command from inside the IDE terminal

Answer (score 3):

I think that answers here are not fully out of topic, but from my point of view, my case is exactly the same as that of the author. I had already installed java 8, 11, and 13. All of them resides at:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Nevertheless when I tried to find the path of JDK 17 it resides:

`/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk`

I use **Mac OS Big Sur** and the JDK was installed with **homebrew**

Answer (score 3):

Brew now supports searching old formulae and allowing you to install a specific version.  I'm using `Homebrew 3.5.2-117-gb941470`

1. Create a local tap: `brew tap-new --no-git local/openjdk`
2. Ask Brew to find the formulae of the version you want: `brew extract --version 17.0.2 openjdk local/openjdk`
3. Install Java 17 using your new local tap: `brew install openjdk@17.0.2`
4. Link the JDK into the MacOS JVM Dir: `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk17.0.2.jdk`
5. Check Java 17 is available: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
6. Set Java Home: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v17)`
7. Check current version of Java is correct...

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
```

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is specifically if you use Intellij on a Mac**

Within IntelliJ, you can use the IDE to add new JDKs of selected versions from common vendors.  Instructions for this are here:

- [Setup the project JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk)

When setting up the JDK, you can either:

1. Select a pre-existing JDK which has been registered with the IDE OR
2. Use the **Add JDK** option to add a new JDK which you previously downloaded and installed using the method outlined in [Basil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69876906/1155209) OR
3. Use the **Download JDK** option to choose a vendor and version of the JDK that the IDE will automatically download, install and make available for selection.

   - The JDKs installed by Idea will be located in the same location as outlined in [Basil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69876906/1155209) for a manual install `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.

One common issue is that the version of the JDK registered for the project differs from the default version used in the terminal.  This can sometimes mean that the app works when run in Idea, then fails when run in the terminal (or, at least that it is executed against a version of the JDK you didn't expect).

To select the version of the JDK to run in the terminal, configure the Java home setting as outlined in [rzwitserloot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875488/1155209).

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`
```

Also, some tools such as the openjfx maven plugin will not use the java version selected in Idea when executing a call to a JDK tool like jlink, but will instead have their own mechanism for finding a JDK to use (e.g. look at JAVA_HOME or use the [Maven toolchains plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)).  So it is always good to check the JAVA_HOME variable and ensure that it is set to a reasonable value, both for terminal execution and for effective use of Java development tools that may rely on it.

Comment: I noticed later. It was cool.

Comment: Mine still doesn't work: "Could not read 'https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/16/ga/mac/aarch64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk' as it does not exist"

Comment: The [adoptionjdk](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) site was replaced by [adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=19).  The adoptopenjdk site warns you of this when you visit the site. Recent releases are not distributed by adoptopenjdk, in particular it does not have releases for modern non-Intel macs. Adoptium JavaFX 19 includes a release for your architecture. Other distributions such as liberica, zulu, oracle openjfx, etc also have packages for M series macs.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this in two simple steps:

1. `brew install openjdk@17`
2. `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Re-open the terminal and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The following method installs Java without the need for any additional tools or package managers.

<s>Go to https://jdk.java.net/17/ and download the latest macOS archive.</s>

Download the latest Adoptium release for the Java 17 branch by going to https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/ and be sure to select the `tar.gz` version.

The archive is either for x64 (Intel CPU) or for AArch64 (Apple Silicon / M1 CPU).

Then, open a Terminal, and extract the downloaded archive to the system path for Java virtual machines:

```
cd Downloads
tar xzf OpenJDK17U-jdk_aarch64_mac_hotspot_17.0.5_8.tar.gz -C /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```